# Determine if a process exists from its Process ID

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I want to know in my program if a process with a certain ID exists. I implemented the following function to achieve that, which checks if `/proc/<PID>/maps` exist. However, I notice that even If I kill a function with a given ID, this function still returns 1. Is there any better way of achieving what I'm trying to do and if not what is the problem with this code if any, why is it returning 1 when it should be returning 0.

```
int proc_exists(pid_t pid)
{
    stringstream ss (stringstream::out);

    ss << dec << pid;

    string path = "/proc/" + ss.str() + "/maps"; 

    ifstream fp( path.c_str() );

    if ( !fp )
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you waiting between issuing the kill and checking that it's exited?  What happens if you do 'ps -ef | grep _PID_'?

Comment: Ya I'm calling proc_exists in a loop, waiting for the process to be killed. Now that I check with ps -ef | grep, it says defunt function. What is defunt function?

Comment: It means that the process is no-longer-running; However, it has not been cleaned up via a call to `wait()` or `waitpid()`.  It is still a valid target for signals, and still has an entry in the process table.

Comment: Please try to be more careful with your use of the words *process* and *function*. They don't mean the same things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `kill()` with signal `0`:

```
if (0 == kill(pid, 0))
{
    // Process exists.
}
```

From [`man kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill):

> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a process ID or process group ID.

Comment: Don't forget that PIDs are recycled. A determined attacker can go through all the PIDs with some quick forks and get their own process to have the same PID as one you're looking for.

Comment: @user1018562, what does `kill()` return and what is the value of `errno`?

Comment: Now I see that the process I'm trying to kill is not exactly killed but its status is set to defunct. Any idea what is a defunct function?

Answer (score 9):

To overcome the possibility of the process existing as zombie, I used the following:

```
bool is_pid_running(pid_t pid) {

    while(waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG) > 0) {
        // Wait for defunct....
    }

    if (0 == kill(pid, 0))
        return 1; // Process exists

    return 0;
}
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
bool checkPidRunning(pid_t pid){
    if (kill(pid, 0) == -1 && errno == ESRCH) {
            return false; // process not exist
    }else 
    return true;
}
```